# Browsers not displaying XFORMS controls

Tags: xhtml, xforms

I am learning XForms. And i am trying to display this in browsers like IE9, Chrome and Firefox 14.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
   <head>
      <title>Hello World in XForms</title>
      <xf:model>
         <xf:instance xmlns="">
            <data>
               <PersonGivenName/>
            </data>
         </xf:instance>
      </xf:model>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Type your first name in the input box. <br/>
        If you are running XForms, the output should be displayed in the output area.</p>   
         <xf:input ref="PersonGivenName" incremental="true">
            <xf:label>Please enter your first name: </xf:label>
         </xf:input>
         <br />
         <xf:output value="concat('Hello ', PersonGivenName, '. We hope you like XForms!')">
            <xf:label>Output: </xf:label>
         </xf:output>
   </body>
</html>
```

But textbox is not appearing. What is the problem? I have tried to search Xfroms plugins for browsers but found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alain Couthures has already pointed out, there is currently no native support for XForms in browsers (and apparently no prospect of it in future).  You will need to install either a client-side or a server-side implementation of XForms, and then you should start to see results.

Available client-side implementations include

- [XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms.htm) (which Alain Couthures wrote and which is often used for its simplicity of setup)
- [Ubiquity XForms](http://code.google.com/p/ubiquity-xforms/) (an ongoing project mostly carried by Mark Birbeck; widely regarded as promising, but not well documented last I looked)
- The [EMC Documentum XForms Engine, aka Formula](https://community.emc.com/docs/DOC-4345) (looked very polished; documentation is aimed at those integrating it with other EMC products)

Prominent server-side implementations include

- [Orbeon](http://www.orbeon.com/) (perhaps the best documented of all XForms products)
- [BetterFORM](http://www.betterform.de/en/index.html) (successor to the Chiba project)

Several of these have active user-community mailing lists.

There are also non-browser-based implementations which use languages other than HTML as the host document language (IBM Forms and Open Office).

Answer (score 4):

XForms is not natively supported in browsers but there are client-side implementations such as XSLTForms (which is based on XSLT and Javascript).

-Alain